# Select specific elemets from a website in VB.net (WebScraping)

Tags: vb.net, web-scraping

I found a website where I can look up vehicle inspections in Denmark. I need to extract some information from the page and loop through a series of license plates. Lets take this car as an example: http://selvbetjening.trafikstyrelsen.dk/Sider/resultater.aspx?Reg=as87640

Here on the left table, you can see some basic information about the vehicle. On the right, you can see a list of the inspections for this specific car. I need a script, which can check if the car has any inspections and then grab the link to each of the inspection reports. Lets take the first inspection from the example. I would like to extract the onclick text from each of the inspections.

The first inspection link would be: 
**location.href="/Sider/synsrapport.aspx?Inspection=18014439&Vin=VF7X1REVF72378327"**

or if you could extract the inspection ID and Vin variable from the URL immediately:

**Inspection ID:** *18014439*

**Vin:** *VF7X1REVF72378327*

Here is an example of a car which don't have any inspections yet, if you want to see what that looks like: http://selvbetjening.trafikstyrelsen.dk/Sider/resultater.aspx?Reg=as87400

*Current Solution plan:*

1. Download the HTML source code as a String in VB.net
2. Search the string and extract the specific parts.
3. Store it in a StringBuilder and upload this to my SQL server

Is this the most efficient way, or do you know of any libraries which is used to specific extract elements from a website in VB.net! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use Java libraries HtmlUnit or Jsoup to webscrape the page.
Here's an example using HtmlUnit:

```
    LogFactory.getFactory().setAttribute("org.apache.commons.logging.Log", "org.apache.commons.logging.impl.NoOpLog");

    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(Level.OFF); 
    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.commons.httpclient").setLevel(Level.OFF);

    WebClient client = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
    client.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    client.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    
    HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://selvbetjening.trafikstyrelsen.dk/Sider/resultater.aspx?Reg=as87640");
    HtmlTable inspectionsTable = (HtmlTable) page.getElementById("tblInspections");
    
    Map<String, String> inspections = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (HtmlTableRow row: inspectionsTable.getRows()) {
        String[] splitRow = row.getAttribute("onclick").split("=");
        
        if (splitRow.length >= 4) {
            String id = splitRow[2].split("&")[0];
            String vin = splitRow[3].replace("\"", "");
            
            inspections.put(id, vin);
            System.out.println(id + " " + vin);
        }
    }
```